# Checkbox Using Razor syntax in mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to display a checkbox in view using razor syntax.
the model property IsActive should be int.
Model is:-

```
public class Student
    {
        public int StudentID { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int IsActive { get; set; }           
}
```

View is:-

```
<div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsActive)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsActive)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsActive)
    </div>
```

I should display checkbox and if checkbox is checked,1 should be saved to the database and if umchecked 0 should be saved.

Pls help me...
Thanks..

Comment: guessing the data table was using an int or bit... a lot of sql tables get setup that way.. if so, create a bool for the checkbox, then use an [if] in the controller to convert the value to the int or bit required for your table. if (ckActive) { isActive = 1; } else { isActive = 0; }

Answer (score 3):

What don't you understand in the error message ? You can't use CheckBoxFor for an int property.

You should change your model and set

```
public bool IsActive {get;set;}
```

Now, there's probably a good reason for it to be an int, but hard to say why with your code...

if IsActive can be only 0 or 1, you should use a ViewModel class, and use a boolean property, which you will map to your class.

```
public class StudentViewModel
    {
        public int StudentID { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }           
}
```

then when you get your student from your db (in your "GET" action")

something like that (rustic)

```
public ActionResult StudentEdit(int id) {
  var student = getStudentById(id);
  var model = new StudentViewModel {
                  StudentId = student.StudentID,
                  Code = student.Code,
                  Description = student.Description,
                  IsActive = student.IsActive == 1 
              };

  return View(model);
}
```

Your view should be typed with StudentViewModel

```
@model StudentViewModel
```

then in your POST action, reverse

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult StudentEdit(StudentViewModel model) {
    var student = getStudentById(model.StudentID);
    student.Code = model.Code;
    student.Description = model.Description;
    student.IsActive = model.IsActive ? 1 : 0;
    UpdateStudent(student);

    return Redirect...
}
```

**EDIT** :

This is a really rustic answer, and I'm sure you could do better.

For that, we would need  some more infos :

Are you using Entity Framework (version) ?

If yes, Code first, Database first, model first ?

Which database is behind ?

Can you change something to the database ?

What type has IsActive in database ?

Comment: I want int in model. public int Is Active{get;set;}.

Comment: @user1697789 but it has limited values ? Say 1 or 0 ? If not, how do you think you can represent 2, or 10, or 24 in a checkbox ?

Comment: please help.my model should be int not bool.But i should get checkbox for that.

Comment: Are you sure you want a checkbox instead of a radiobutton? Still not sure why you'd want to use an `int` as the type.

Comment: It is the task assigned to me

Comment: @user1697789 we can't do anything if you don't answer our questions... What kind of values can you have in IsActive ? 0, 1 or any integer value ?

Comment: why not bind the model to a bool property and then have an exposed int property that you can read from as well? e.g. public bool IsActive {get;set;} and public int IsActiveAsInt { get { IsActive ? 1 : 0; }

Comment: @user1697789 edited. But they are many other ways, I thought also to glosrob's solution, but we don't know your real context, so it's quite hard to help you.

Comment: public int IsActiveAsInt { get { IsActive ? 1 : 0; }} ..it shows error

Comment: @Raphaël Althaus model should be int,not bool.But it should display checkbox and if check it,1 should be saved to database.if unchecked 0 should be saved.

Comment: @user1697789 if my edited answer doesn't fit your needs, try to answer to the questions in my answer (last part) : copy questions and fill the answer in your main question would be perfect.

Comment: mvc4 is used.code first using model first approach..SQL SERVER 2008 R2.IsActive is int.Is shoul store only 1 and 0

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework (version) ?EF4

If yes, Code first, Database first, model first ?model first

Which database is behind ?SqlServer 2008 R2

Can you change something to the database ?cant understand

What type has IsActive in database ?int

Comment: @user1697789 if you use modelFirst, you can set IsActive as boolean... It will be stored as a Bit field in SQL server, which permit only 0 or 1 (there's no "bool" type in SQL server, but Bit type fits boolean values requirement. If you can't change the model (which is bad if it tries to store boolean values in an integer field), then use the ViewModel approach.

Comment: got the answer- public int Active { get; set; }
        public bool ActiveBool
        {
            get { return Active > 0; }
            set { Active = value ? 1 : 0; }
        }

Answer (score 0):

`IsActive` should be a bool, `@Html.CheckBoxFor()` helper method expects boolean parameter

change code to

```
public bool IsActive { get; set; }
```